# Triggering a popup with a href but no destination URL - this must be wrong?

Tags: html

I have a popup that is triggered by the user on "click here to enter your email"

Here's the code:

```
<a href="#" class="onclick-coupon">click here to enter your email</a>
```

The css class triggers the popup, so all good - but I am sure that the empty URL with a # is wrong - or is it?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on where you want it to redirect, "#" means it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Apparently, this is best practice = href="#!" (note the '!')